# how to convert data to standard json

Tags: python-3.x

```
messages=%5B%7B%22values%22%3A+%7B%22momentum%22%3A+%220.00%22%7D%2C+%22exchange%22%3A+%22binance%22%2C+%22market%22%3A+%22BNT%2FETH%22%2C+%22base_currency%22%3A+%22BNT%22%2C+%22quote_currency%22%3A+%22ETH%22%2C+%22indicator%22%3A+%22momentum%22%2C+%22indicator_number%22%3A+0%2C+%22analysis%22%3A+%7B%22config%22%3A+%7B%22enabled%22%3A+true%2C+%22alert_enabled%22%3A+true%2C+%22alert_frequency%22%3A+%22once%22%2C+%22signal%22%3A+%5B%22momentum%22%5D%2C+%22hot%22%3A+0%2C+%22cold%22%3A+0%2C+%22candle_period%22%3A+%224h%22%2C+%22period_count%22%3A+10%7D%2C+%22status%22%3A+%22hot%22%7D%2C+%22status%22%3A+%22hot%22%2C+%22last_status%22%3A+%22hot%22%2C+%22prices%22%3A+%22+Open%3A+0.000989+High%3A+0.000998+Low%3A+0.000980+Close%3A+0.000998%22%2C+%22lrsi%22%3A+%22%22%2C+%22creation_date%22%3A+%222020-05-10+16%3A16%3A23%22%2C+%22hot_cold_label%22%3A+%22%22%2C+%22indicator_label%22%3A+%22%22%2C+%22price_value%22%3A+%7B%22open%22%3A+0.000989%2C+%22high%22%3A+0.000998%2C+%22low%22%3A+0.00098%2C+%22close%22%3A+0.000998%7D%2C+%22decimal_format%22%3A+%22%25.6f%22%7D%2C+%7B%22values%22%3A+%7B%22leading_span_a%22%3A+%220.00%22%2C+%22leading_span_b%22%3A+%220.00%22%7D%2C+%22exchange%22%3A+%22binance%22%2C+%22market%22%3A+%22BNT%2FETH%22%2C+%22base_currency%22%3A+%22BNT%22%2C+%22quote_currency%22%3A+%22ETH%22%2C+%22indicator%22%3A+%22ichimoku%22%2C+%22indicator_number%22%3A+1%2C+%22analysis%22%3A+%7B%22config%22%3A+%7B%22enabled%22%3A+true%2C+%22alert_enabled%22%3A+true%2C+%22alert_frequency%22%3A+%22once%22%2C+%22signal%22%3A+%5B%22leading_span_a%22%2C+%22leading_span_b%22%5D%2C+%22hot%22%3A+true%2C+%22cold%22%3A+true%2C+%22candle_period%22%3A+%224h%22%2C+%22hot_label%22%3A+%22Bullish+Alert%22%2C+%22cold_label%22%3A+%22Bearish+Alert%22%2C+%22indicator_label%22%3A+%22ICHIMOKU+4+hr%22%2C+%22mute_cold%22%3A+false%7D%2C+%22status%22%3A+%22cold%22%7D%2C+%22status%22%3A+%22cold%22%2C+%22last_status%22%3A+%22cold%22%2C+%22prices%22%3A+%22+Open%3A+0.000989+High%3A+0.000998+Low%3A+0.000980+Close%3A+0.000998%22%2C+%22lrsi%22%3A+%22%22%2C+%22creation_date%22%3A+%222020-05-10+16%3A16%3A23%22%2C+%22hot_cold_label%22%3A+%22Bearish+Alert%22%2C+%22indicator_label%22%3A+%22ICHIMOKU+4+hr%22%2C+%22price_value%22%3A+%7B%22open%22%3A+0.000989%2C+%22high%22%3A+0.000998%2C+%22low%22%3A+0.00098%2C+%22close%22%3A+0.000998%7D%2C+%22decimal_format%22%3A+%22%25.6f%22%7D%2C+%7B%22values%22%3A+%7B%22bbp%22%3A+%220.96%22%2C+%22mfi%22%3A+%2298.05%22%7D%2C+%22exchange%22%3A+%22binance%22%2C+%22market%22%3A+%22BNT%2FETH%22%2C+%22base_currency%22%3A+%22BNT%22%2C+%22quote_currency%22%3A+%22ETH%22%2C+%22indicator%22%3A+%22bbp%22%2C+%22indicator_number%22%3A+1%2C+%22analysis%22%3A+%7B%22config%22%3A+%7B%22enabled%22%3A+true%2C+%22alert_enabled%22%3A+true%2C+%22alert_frequency%22%3A+%22once%22%2C+%22candle_period%22%3A+%224h%22%2C+%22period_count%22%3A+20%2C+%22hot%22%3A+0.09%2C+%22cold%22%3A+0.8%2C+%22std_dev%22%3A+2%2C+%22signal%22%3A+%5B%22bbp%22%2C+%22mfi%22%5D%2C+%22hot_label%22%3A+%22Lower+Band%22%2C+%22cold_label%22%3A+%22Upper+Band+BB%22%2C+%22indicator_label%22%3A+%22Bollinger+4+hr%22%2C+%22mute_cold%22%3A+false%7D%2C+%22status%22%3A+%22cold%22%7D%2C+%22status%22%3A+%22cold%22%2C+%22last_status%22%3A+%22cold%22%2C+%22prices%22%3A+%22+Open%3A+0.000989+High%3A+0.000998+Low%3A+0.000980+Close%3A+0.000998%22%2C+%22lrsi%22%3A+%22%22%2C+%22creation_date%22%3A+%222020-05-10+16%3A16%3A23%22%2C+%22hot_cold_label%22%3A+%22Upper+Band+BB%22%2C+%22indicator_label%22%3A+%22Bollinger+4+hr%22%2C+%22price_value%22%3A+%7B%22open%22%3A+0.000989%2C+%22high%22%3A+0.000998%2C+%22low%22%3A+0.00098%2C+%22close%22%3A+0.000998%7D%2C+%22decimal_format%22%3A+%22%25.6f%22%7D%5D
```

i need to convert this data in python3 to standard json for post json api

any solution ?
thanks

Comment: where do achieved that data and what formatting does it have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like it's been URL form encoded.

Try

```py
import urllib.parse
import json

# note **without** the message= part
stuff = "%5B%7B%22values%22%3A+%7B%22momentum%22%3A+%220.00%22%7D%2C+%22exchange%22%3A+%22binance%22%2C+%22market%22%3A+%22BNT%2FETH%22%2C+%22base_currency%22%3A+%22BNT%22%2C+%22quote_currency%22%3A+%22ETH%22%2C+%22indicator%22%3A+%22momentum%22%2C+%22indicator_number%22%3A+0%2C+%22analysis%22%3A+%7B%22config%22%3A+%7B%22enabled%22%3A+true%2C+%22alert_enabled%22%3A+true%2C+%22alert_frequency%22%3A+%22once%22%2C+%22signal%22%3A+%5B%22momentum%22%5D%2C+%22hot%22%3A+0%2C+%22cold%22%3A+0%2C+%22candle_period%22%3A+%224h%22%2C+%22period_count%22%3A+10%7D%2C+%22status%22%3A+%22hot%22%7D%2C+%22status%22%3A+%22hot%22%2C+%22last_status%22%3A+%22hot%22%2C+%22prices%22%3A+%22+Open%3A+0.000989+High%3A+0.000998+Low%3A+0.000980+Close%3A+0.000998%22%2C+%22lrsi%22%3A+%22%22%2C+%22creation_date%22%3A+%222020-05-10+16%3A16%3A23%22%2C+%22hot_cold_label%22%3A+%22%22%2C+%22indicator_label%22%3A+%22%22%2C+%22price_value%22%3A+%7B%22open%22%3A+0.000989%2C+%22high%22%3A+0.000998%2C+%22low%22%3A+0.00098%2C+%22close%22%3A+0.000998%7D%2C+%22decimal_format%22%3A+%22%25.6f%22%7D%2C+%7B%22values%22%3A+%7B%22leading_span_a%22%3A+%220.00%22%2C+%22leading_span_b%22%3A+%220.00%22%7D%2C+%22exchange%22%3A+%22binance%22%2C+%22market%22%3A+%22BNT%2FETH%22%2C+%22base_currency%22%3A+%22BNT%22%2C+%22quote_currency%22%3A+%22ETH%22%2C+%22indicator%22%3A+%22ichimoku%22%2C+%22indicator_number%22%3A+1%2C+%22analysis%22%3A+%7B%22config%22%3A+%7B%22enabled%22%3A+true%2C+%22alert_enabled%22%3A+true%2C+%22alert_frequency%22%3A+%22once%22%2C+%22signal%22%3A+%5B%22leading_span_a%22%2C+%22leading_span_b%22%5D%2C+%22hot%22%3A+true%2C+%22cold%22%3A+true%2C+%22candle_period%22%3A+%224h%22%2C+%22hot_label%22%3A+%22Bullish+Alert%22%2C+%22cold_label%22%3A+%22Bearish+Alert%22%2C+%22indicator_label%22%3A+%22ICHIMOKU+4+hr%22%2C+%22mute_cold%22%3A+false%7D%2C+%22status%22%3A+%22cold%22%7D%2C+%22status%22%3A+%22cold%22%2C+%22last_status%22%3A+%22cold%22%2C+%22prices%22%3A+%22+Open%3A+0.000989+High%3A+0.000998+Low%3A+0.000980+Close%3A+0.000998%22%2C+%22lrsi%22%3A+%22%22%2C+%22creation_date%22%3A+%222020-05-10+16%3A16%3A23%22%2C+%22hot_cold_label%22%3A+%22Bearish+Alert%22%2C+%22indicator_label%22%3A+%22ICHIMOKU+4+hr%22%2C+%22price_value%22%3A+%7B%22open%22%3A+0.000989%2C+%22high%22%3A+0.000998%2C+%22low%22%3A+0.00098%2C+%22close%22%3A+0.000998%7D%2C+%22decimal_format%22%3A+%22%25.6f%22%7D%2C+%7B%22values%22%3A+%7B%22bbp%22%3A+%220.96%22%2C+%22mfi%22%3A+%2298.05%22%7D%2C+%22exchange%22%3A+%22binance%22%2C+%22market%22%3A+%22BNT%2FETH%22%2C+%22base_currency%22%3A+%22BNT%22%2C+%22quote_currency%22%3A+%22ETH%22%2C+%22indicator%22%3A+%22bbp%22%2C+%22indicator_number%22%3A+1%2C+%22analysis%22%3A+%7B%22config%22%3A+%7B%22enabled%22%3A+true%2C+%22alert_enabled%22%3A+true%2C+%22alert_frequency%22%3A+%22once%22%2C+%22candle_period%22%3A+%224h%22%2C+%22period_count%22%3A+20%2C+%22hot%22%3A+0.09%2C+%22cold%22%3A+0.8%2C+%22std_dev%22%3A+2%2C+%22signal%22%3A+%5B%22bbp%22%2C+%22mfi%22%5D%2C+%22hot_label%22%3A+%22Lower+Band%22%2C+%22cold_label%22%3A+%22Upper+Band+BB%22%2C+%22indicator_label%22%3A+%22Bollinger+4+hr%22%2C+%22mute_cold%22%3A+false%7D%2C+%22status%22%3A+%22cold%22%7D%2C+%22status%22%3A+%22cold%22%2C+%22last_status%22%3A+%22cold%22%2C+%22prices%22%3A+%22+Open%3A+0.000989+High%3A+0.000998+Low%3A+0.000980+Close%3A+0.000998%22%2C+%22lrsi%22%3A+%22%22%2C+%22creation_date%22%3A+%222020-05-10+16%3A16%3A23%22%2C+%22hot_cold_label%22%3A+%22Upper+Band+BB%22%2C+%22indicator_label%22%3A+%22Bollinger+4+hr%22%2C+%22price_value%22%3A+%7B%22open%22%3A+0.000989%2C+%22high%22%3A+0.000998%2C+%22low%22%3A+0.00098%2C+%22close%22%3A+0.000998%7D%2C+%22decimal_format%22%3A+%22%25.6f%22%7D%5D"

parsed = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(stuff) # <<< encoded form, get rid of +
as_json = json.loads(parsed)
print(as_json)
```

gives me

```
[{'values': {'momentum': '0.00'}, 'exchange': 'binance', 'market': 'BNT/ETH', 'base_currency': 'BNT', 'quote_currency': 'ETH', 'indicator': 'momentum', 'indicator_number': 0, 'analysis': {'config': {'enabled': True, 'alert_enabled': True, 'alert_frequency': 'once', 'signal': ['momentum'], 'hot': 0, 'cold': 0, 'candle_period': '4h', 'period_count': 10}, 'status': 'hot'}, 'status': 'hot', 'last_status': 'hot', 'prices': ' Open: 0.000989 High: 0.000998 Low: 0.000980 Close: 0.000998', 'lrsi': '', 'creation_date': '2020-05-10 16:16:23', 'hot_cold_label': '', 'indicator_label': '', 'price_value': {'open': 0.000989, 'high': 0.000998, 'low': 0.00098, 'close': 0.000998}, 'decimal_format': '%.6f'}, {'values': {'leading_span_a': '0.00', 'leading_span_b': '0.00'}, 'exchange': 'binance', 'market': 'BNT/ETH', 'base_currency': 'BNT', 'quote_currency': 'ETH', 'indicator': 'ichimoku', 'indicator_number': 1, 'analysis': {'config': {'enabled': True, 'alert_enabled': True, 'alert_frequency': 'once', 'signal': ['leading_span_a', 'leading_span_b'], 'hot': True, 'cold': True, 'candle_period': '4h', 'hot_label': 'Bullish Alert', 'cold_label': 'Bearish Alert', 'indicator_label': 'ICHIMOKU 4 hr', 'mute_cold': False}, 'status': 'cold'}, 'status': 'cold', 'last_status': 'cold', 'prices': ' Open: 0.000989 High: 0.000998 Low: 0.000980 Close: 0.000998', 'lrsi': '', 'creation_date': '2020-05-10 16:16:23', 'hot_cold_label': 'Bearish Alert', 'indicator_label': 'ICHIMOKU 4 hr', 'price_value': {'open': 0.000989, 'high': 0.000998, 'low': 0.00098, 'close': 0.000998}, 'decimal_format': '%.6f'}, {'values': {'bbp': '0.96', 'mfi': '98.05'}, 'exchange': 'binance', 'market': 'BNT/ETH', 'base_currency': 'BNT', 'quote_currency': 'ETH', 'indicator': 'bbp', 'indicator_number': 1, 'analysis': {'config': {'enabled': True, 'alert_enabled': True, 'alert_frequency': 'once', 'candle_period': '4h', 'period_count': 20, 'hot': 0.09, 'cold': 0.8, 'std_dev': 2, 'signal': ['bbp', 'mfi'], 'hot_label': 'Lower Band', 'cold_label': 'Upper Band BB', 'indicator_label': 'Bollinger 4 hr', 'mute_cold': False}, 'status': 'cold'}, 'status': 'cold', 'last_status': 'cold', 'prices': ' Open: 0.000989 High: 0.000998 Low: 0.000980 Close: 0.000998', 'lrsi': '', 'creation_date': '2020-05-10 16:16:23', 'hot_cold_label': 'Upper Band BB', 'indicator_label': 'Bollinger 4 hr', 'price_value': {'open': 0.000989, 'high': 0.000998, 'low': 0.00098, 'close': 0.000998}, 'decimal_format': '%.6f'}]
```

Whereas if you want a JSON string to POST somewhere, call `as_string = json.dumps(parsed)`